# Javascipt returns "undefined" when using innerHTML of element as key

Tags: javascript, dictionary, undefined

HTML

```
<h1 id="mojaTata"></h1>
```

javascript, dictionary with questions and answers

```
pitanja_i_odgovori = {
        "Predjeni put": "S =  * t",
        "x vektora koji je dat kao A(x1;y1)" : "x1 = r1 cos(α1)" ,
        ... etc
}
```

setting random key as value in h1 element(id=mojaTata), this is our "question" (we "inject" question to h1(id=mojaTata) for our user to see random Physics question), this part works great

```
for (key in pitanja_i_odgovori) {
        len += 1
}
document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML = Object.keys( pitanja_i_odgovori[Math.floor(Math.random() * len) ];
```

Here is the problem, I would like to get answer to our question that is in h1(id=mojaTata)

```
alert( pitanja_i_odgovori[document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML] );
```

This returns "undefined", when I console.log(document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML) i get output (answer) no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to set the question is faulty. Code to alert the answer does not appear to have a problem.

```
document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML
= Object.keys( pitanja_i_odgovori[Math.floor(Math.random() * len) ];
```

won't compile because it's missing a `)`, which belongs between `pitanja_i_odgovori` and `[Math.floor...`. This also means the closing `)` should now be a `]`.

Changing setting the question to

```
document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML
= Object.keys( pitanja_i_odgovori)[Math.floor(Math.random() * len)]
```

gets the alert of the answer to work correctly.

While there are multiple ways of implementing question and answer presentation, consider using the header's `textContent` property instead of `innerHTML` to prevent errors caused by `<`,'>' or '&' in question text being interpreted as HTML.

---

**test code:**

```js
"use strict"
// JavaScript, dictionary with questions and answers

const pitanja_i_odgovori = {
        "question 1": "answer 1",
        "question 2" : "answer 2",
        "google translate roditelj": "parent"
        // ... and more
}
/**** custom code *****/
const pitanja = Object.keys(pitanja_i_odgovori);
const len = pitanja.length;
const roditelj = document.getElementById("mojaTata");
function setPitanje(i){  
    roditelj.textContent = pitanja[i];
}
function setRandomPitanje() {
    setPitanje( Math.floor(len * Math.random()));
}
function logOdgovor() {
    // get answer (odgover) using the content of the H1 header
    console.log( pitanja_i_odgovori[ roditelj.textContent]);
}
/***** posted code with correction ****/
function postedSetMethod() {
    document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML
    = Object.keys( pitanja_i_odgovori)[Math.floor(Math.random() * len)]
}
function postedAnswerMethod() {
    alert( pitanja_i_odgovori[document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML] );
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="setRandomPitanje()">set random question</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="logOdgovor()">log answer</button> 
(custom code)<br>
<button type="button" onclick="postedSetMethod()">set random question</button>
<button type="button" onclick="postedAnswerMethod()">alert answer</button> (post code after correction)
<h1 id="mojaTata"></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see that you really notice small details like this one plus a great explanation. I made your answer "accepted answer."

Answer (score 0):

For your Math.random to work you have to multiplay it by the length of the array you are applying to

try this

```
<h1 id="mojaTata"></h1>
  <button id="button">subm</button>
<script>
 const pitanja_i_odgovori = {
    "Predjeni put": "S =  * t",
    "x vektora koji je dat kao A(x1;y1)" : "x1 = r1 cos(α1)" ,

}
const btn=document.getElementById('button')
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
const keys=Object.keys(pitanja_i_odgovori)
console.log(keys)
const randomkey =keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length) ] //for your Math.random to work you have to multiplay it by the length of the array you are applying to 


document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML = randomkey
alert( pitanja_i_odgovori[document.getElementById('mojaTata').innerHTML] );
})

</script>
```

Comment: Great answer! I was struggling with it a lot. Thank you!